# Error : Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql

I tried to write this in one of my SQL stored procedure. Just a simple logic to just check if the `@kPortalOrigin` exists in the table `[cli].[tbl_S_PortalOrigin]`:

```
 IF (COUNT ((SELECT kPortalOrigin 
             FROM [cli].[tbl_S_PortalOrigin] 
             WHERE kPortalOrigin = @kPortalOrigin)) = 0) 
     RAISERROR('Portal Origin is invalid!', 16, 1)
```

However, I get this error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Any help? Thanks. And I would not mind an explanation why this error occurs.

Comment: If your table happens to contain millions of rows, this will be highly ineffective and potentially take a very long time to complete. I'd strongly suggest you check out the `IF EXISTS (....)` alternative instead

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `IF` in standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if EXISTs ((select kPortalOrigin from [cli].[tbl_S_PortalOrigin] where kPortalOrigin = @kPortalOrigin)) RAISERROR('Portal Origin is invalid!',16,1)
```

this will works.